# Recursive Reduce method in ES6 / Immutable

Tags: javascript, recursion, reduce, immutable.js

Hope this isn't too difficult a question without context, but here goes nothing. So, I inherited this code from someone, and I can't seem to get it to work!

We're making a Go game. We want to scan a set of pieces on the board and see if they're empty or not. An empty square is called a 'liberty'. Now, at the bottom of the function there we're creating a new 2D array 'visitedBoard' that keeps track of where we've scanned so far.

PROBLEM, the current implementation allows for liberties to be scanned twice! It only seems to be marking something as 'visited' in the board when it is either empty or another color (0), not when it's 1.

BTW, at the bottom - we're iterating through neighbors, which is a 4 item array of objects {row: 2, col: 3} and then recursively running it through this function.

Any assistance is helpful. I'm new to this functional / immutable business.

```
const getLiberties = function (board, point, color) {

if (board.get(point.row).get(point.col) === C.VISITED) {
return 0; // we already counted this point

} else if (board.get(point.row).get(point.col) === C.EMPTY) {
return 1; // point is a liberty

} else if (board.get(point.row).get(point.col) !== color) {
return 0; // point has an opposing stone in it
}

const neighbours = getNeighbours(board, point)
const visitedBoard = board.setIn([point.row, point.col], C.VISITED)

return neighbours.reduce(
(liberties, neighbour) => liberties + getLiberties(visitedBoard, 
neighbour, color), 0)}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. instead of `.get(point.row).get(point.col)` you can use `.getIn([point.row, point.col])`
2. inside reduce you always use same visitedBoard for all calls. You have to re-assign new value to variable after reduce callback call

[image]